# Display all the lines in file that contain a keyword.

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program which reads a text file and asks for the user to input a word, the program should then print all lines containing that line..

This is my code at the moment:

```
f = open ("G:/test.txt", "r");     
line = f.readlines()        
find_word = raw_input("Enter word here:")    
if find_word in f:    
    print find_word    
f.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that loop be `in line:`?

Comment: That's a horrible question title.

Comment: Epic fail title and epic fail question. I didn't see the question mark.

Answer (score 3):

this should work:

Use `with` statement while handling file, as it takes care of the closing of the file.

```
with open("G:/test.txt") as f:
   final_word=raw_input("Enter word here:")
   for line in f:                #iterate over each line of f
       if final_word in line:    #if final_word in line , then print it
           print line.strip()
```

Comment: "print line," (with comma) instead of "print line.strip()" should work as well. In python3 you could use print(line, end="") to suppress the line break.

Answer (score 1):

Your line list contained words like this:

```
['dom\n', 'hello\n', 'world']
```

Notice the newlines? You need to strip them.

```
line = open("test.txt").read().splitlines()
find_word = raw_input("Enter word here:")    
if find_word in line:    
    print find_word
```